# How to split an array into multple arrays each with a unique name

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array = [A,1,0,1,0,1,B,1,0,0,1,A,1]
I need to split this array into multiple arrays. The split will occur at the "A" or "B" position as seen in the new arrays below. The names of the new arrays use the string "group" plus an incremented number starting with 1 or 0.
The end result should look like:

```
group1 = [A,1,0,1,0,1]
group2 = [B,1,0,0,1]
group3 = [A,1]
```

I can get the section of the array I need by creating an array (arrTemp), so I can store the positions (indexes) and later use slice() to get the sections I want (A,1,0,1,0,1), (A,1,0,0,1), and (A,1). But I don't know how to store the results of my slice()'s in arrays with unique names incremented by 1. 
This is what I have tried so far:

```
var arr = [A,1,0,1,0,1,B,1,0,0,1,A,1];
arr.forEach(myFunction)
function myFunction(item, index)    {
if ((item=="A") || (item=="B")) {
arrTemp.push(index);
arrTemp=arrTemp; //not sure I need this. I did this so it array would be global
}
}
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
sectArray = arr.slice(arrTemp[i]+1,arrTemp[i + 1])
'group' + [i] = [arrTemp[i],sectArray]; //here is my problem.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to dynamically create variables. That seems tricky and probably won't work. What you should probably have is some collection of results. Probably a parent array that holds all of them.

For example:

`var containerArray = [];`

Then:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    sectArray = arr.slice(arrTemp[i]+1,arrTemp[i + 1])
    containerArray[i] = [arrTemp[i],sectArray];
}
```

Now `containerArray` will have all of your stuff. You can also do this with an object:

`var containerObject = {};`

And the same thing after.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At first I didn't see how simple and close I was to the solution. I could've simply changed my line from  'group' + [i] to group[i] and added var group = [] at the beginning. I just didn't realize I could use a "parent array" to hold stuff.

Comment: @MarkL exactly! you were on the right track. Good luck!

Comment: Hopefully you can help me here. Although the solution did create an array "with all my stuff"; later when I had to grab pieces such as:
group[0][2] or group[0][4]
I noticed that I only have two elements (group[0][2] or group[0][4]
)
It seems like the process put "A" in group[0][0] and 
"1,0,1,0,1" in group[0][0][1]. How do I fix this?
group[0][2] was resulting in "undefined".

Comment: I did post another question asking about the problem only to realize the root of the issue was here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643267/how-to-add-a-element-to-an-array-inside-another-array

Comment: My fix was to add a "forEach function:
group[I] = [arrTemp[i]];
sectArray.forEach(runThis);
function runThis(item,index){
group[I].push(item);
}
Now each element is pushed as an individual element and does not get "wrapped" in a array or group.
Is there a better way to do this?
}

Comment: @MarkL only saw this now, sorry! Can you please make a jsfiddle showing your problem? I can help you in there.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I can create a jsfiddle to show the problem. In reality these functions are running on a computer based training course, more specifically in a lesson tests section. Many of the elements are generated dynamically between 3 pages. For me (with my limited knowledge) to reproduce the behavior in small scale would be daunting. Thanks for the support anyway.

Comment: Know that what I did is working. In essence because I was pushing a "group of elements" to an array, the array "intelligently" packaged them in a group. Breaking up the push() into one element at a time allowed the array to contain individual elements. But I'm sure there is a more elegant and streamlined way to write this...;)

Comment: Correction for post above:
"(group[0][2] or group[0][4] ) meant to say  (group[0][2] or group[0][4] are undefined. only group[0][0] and group [0][1] are defined)"

Comment: @MarkL that makes more sense. That's because there are only two elements in this `[arrTemp[i],sectArray]`. `arrayTemp[i]` would be in the `0` position, and `sectArray` would be in the `1` position. As for group, you could use `group[0], group[1], ..., group[n - 1]` where `n` is the number of elements in `group`.

Comment: Thanks for input. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

you only need one loop here, keep an empty temp array, iterate over arr and keep pushing elements in temp each time you see 'A' or 'B' push temp to final array, and at last push temp once more into final array because last section will be left.

```js
var arr = ['A',1,0,1,0,1,'B',1,0,0,1,'A',1];
var temp = [];
var sectArray = [];
arr.forEach(myFunction)
function myFunction(item, index)    {
if (((item=="A") || (item=="B")) && temp.length) {
sectArray.push(temp);
temp = [item];
}else{
 temp.push(item);
}
}
sectArray.push(temp);
console.log(sectArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think you may be on to something regarding only needing one loop. But I tried your code and "sectArray" simply resulted in what I had in the beginning ['A',1,0,1,0,1,'B',1,0,0,1,'A',1]. I really need the new arrays with the names (group1, group2, group3, etc) as I will call for these later.

Comment: I checked this again and see it is in fact working as I need it. I am still trying to wrap my brain around what you did and how its working. Thanks again. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution that use a combination of string and array methods:

```js
var data = ['A',1,0,1,0,1,'B',1,0,0,1,'A',1];

var results = data.toString().split(/(?=[a-zA-Z]+)/)
.map(function(value){
  return value.split(',').filter(function (item) {
    return item.length ? true: false;
  })
})
.map(function(item) {
   return item.map(function (value) {
     return isNaN(parseInt(value)) ? value : parseInt(value);
   })
});

console.log(results);

// results = [["A", 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], ["B", 1, 0, 0, 1], ["A", 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. Although I did not use your code example, what you displayed in "results" at the bottom made me realize I could have [arrays] inside arrays. Not sure if I'm using the proper lingo though.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using  [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function.

```js
var x = ["A", 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, "B", 1, 0, 0, 1, "A", 1];


function reformat(arr) {
    var smallArrCounter = 0;
    return arr.reduce(function (acc, item) {
        if (item === "A" || item === "B") {
            acc["group" + (++smallArrCounter)] = [item];
        } else {
            acc["group" + smallArrCounter].push(item);
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});
}

var result =  reformat(x);

console.log(result.group1); // ["A",  1,  0,  1,  0,  1]
console.log(result.group2); // ["B",  1,  0,  0,  1]
console.log(result.group3); // ["A", 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more performant approach that doesn't require two iterations of the array, but my thought is:

1. Determine the indices of the group delimiters (characters)
2. Slice the array into groups based on those delimiters, using either the next index as the end, or `arr.length` if slicing the last group

This has the assumption that the array delimiters may not be known in advance.

```js
const charIndices = [];
const groups = [];
const arr = ['A',1,0,1,0,1,'B',1,0,0,1,'A',1];
// get the indices of the characters
arr.forEach((v, i) => ('' + v).match(/[A-Z]+/) ? charIndices.push(i) : undefined);
// use the found indices to split into groups
charIndices.reduce((a, b, i) => {
   a.push(arr.slice(b, charIndices[i+1] ? charIndices[i+1]-1 : arr.length));
   return a;
}, groups);
console.log(groups);
```