# How to add a element to an array inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my situation. I have the following array.

```
arrParent = [[List1,A,B,C],[List2,E,F,G,H]];
arrChild1 = [List1,A,B,C];
arrChild2 = [List2,E,F,G,H];
```

I want to add "D" to the end of arrChild1.
I am having difficulty targeting the child array in my javascript.

I am using:

```
arrParent[0].push("D")
```

...but the result is not what I want. The result I get is:

```
arrChild[(List1,A,B,C),D];
```

I can verify this my calling:

```
console.log(arrChild1[0] (which displays List1,A,B,C)
console.log(arrChild1[1] (which displays D)
```

I need:

```
arrChild1[0] = List1
arrChild1[1] = A
arrChild1[2] = B
arrChild1[3] = C
arrChild1[4] = D
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `arrChild1 = [[List1, A, B, C]]`?

Comment: Your code should work. Can you try to find more depth in your problem?

Comment: I have test this `var arrParent = [['List1','A','B','C'],['List2','E','F','G','H']]; arrParent[0].push('D'); console.log(arrParent[0]);` The result was as expected: `["List1", "A", "B", "C", "D"]`

Comment: Code works for me.

Comment: To all: Thanks for looking at this. While I don't have the answer just yet I have narrowed the cause to be how the array is being dynamically created using .push() in other functions. I need to look at them.

Comment: To all. I posted a follow up to a solution in another post (by me). Seems like that solution is the root of the problem and why the array is being created with this inner structure. Link below point to this other post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513355/how-to-split-an-array-into-multple-arrays-each-with-a-unique-name

Comment: This is my fix posted on the other post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45513355/how-to-split-an-array-into-multple-arrays-each-with-a-unique-name

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = [1,2,3]; // access like: foo[0] === 1

var bar = [foo, [4,5,6]];
var baz = bar[0]; // baz[0] === 1 same as foo[0]

//so to access an array within array
var fuz = bar[0][0]; // fuz === 1
```